# Best web front-end for massive amounts of data?

Tags: sql-server

We currently give out Excel/Access documents that are sometimes 200,000+ rows. This creates a real pain for our non-tech clients to manipulate the data (it's essentially all the metadata from a hard drive). Plus, a lot of computers can choke on a 500MB Excel document.

We're looking into using something like Amazon AWS or another hosted SQL server. The issue is we need a front end that lets them easily query their individual database/project/whatever (e.g. "show me all the files with ".pdf" extensions or "show me all the files between these dates that are marked as being overwritten", etc).

Preferably something that would give us easy administration over users (e.g. "johndoe" only has access to databases "001, 002, 003" under the "johndoe project"). Co-mingling the data in the same database is a serious (legal) issue.

If it could let the users "tag" entries that would be even better (export to CSV, etc).

I have experience with C# (though not with ASP and only dabbled in MVC3). But, any platform will do (e.g. MySQL + ?) if the software is robust enough.

Trying to avoid having to re-invent the wheel if such a software exists or is easily programmable.

Comment: I know that there's several web services that already do this in the business world, but I don't know their names. However, they do require subscriptions to the service.

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for here is a Content Management System (CMS). In the Microsoft world, SharePoint would be what you are looking for. For open source, you might look at Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this: http://xlinesoft.com/index.htm.
You may find their reporting system useful too.
Please have a go on trial version first. Full version is not very expensive though.